# How does Prototypical Inheritance works in JS

Tags: javascript

I am trying prototypical inheritance in order to calculate distance(). But I am getting an error which is `TypeError: Cannot read property 'x' of undefined`. The error line is marked at the code. I know that the way I am calculating distance() is wrong. But someone can guide me what is the correct way?

```
'use strict';

 function Shape(x,y){
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
  };

  Shape.prototype.distance = function(s1,s2){
    // this.distance = function(s1,s2){
      const xDiff = this.s1.x - this.s2.x;         //error
      const yDiff = this.s1.y - this.s2.y;
      return Math.sqrt(xDiff*xDiff + yDiff*yDiff);      
    // }
  };


 function Circle(x,y,radius){
    Shape.call(this,x,y);
    this.radius = radius;
    this.area = Math.PI*this.radius*this.radius;
};

 function Rectangle(x,y,w,h){
  Shape.call(this,x,y);
  this.width =w;
  this.height =h;
  this.area = this.width * this.height;  
};

Circle.prototype = Object.create(Shape.prototype);
Circle.prototype.constructor = Circle;

Rectangle.prototype = Object.create(Shape.prototype);
Rectangle.prototype.constructor = Rectangle;



const shapes = [
  new Rectangle(3,4,5,6),
  new Circle(0,0,1),
];

shapes.forEach((s) => console.log(s.x, s.y, s.area));
console.log(Shape.prototype.distance(shapes[0],shapes[1]));
```

Comment: What do you think `this.s1` is? Why?

Comment: You never assign `s2` to be a property of the shape (or rectangle or circle). Also, functions should not have `;`s after their final `}`.

Answer (score 0):

Typically when you put a method on the prototype you anticipate it being called on an instance of that class. So, in your example you would do something like:

```
 someShape.distance(someOtherShape)
```

When you do that the `this` in the function refers to the shape on which you called the function. So your distance function would look like this:

```
  Shape.prototype.distance = function(otherShape){
      const xDiff = this.x - otherShape.x;        
      const yDiff = this.y - otherShape.y;
      return Math.sqrt(xDiff*xDiff + yDiff*yDiff);      
  }
```

Then you can call it as a method on one of the objects:

```js
function Shape(x, y) {
  this.x = x;
  this.y = y;
}

Shape.prototype.distance = function(otherShape) {
  const xDiff = this.x - otherShape.x; //error
  const yDiff = this.y - otherShape.y;
  return Math.sqrt(xDiff * xDiff + yDiff * yDiff);
}

let sh1 = new Shape(0, 0)
let sh2 = new Shape(3, 4)

console.log(sh1.distance(sh2))
// or the opposite
console.log(sh2.distance(sh1))
```

If instead you want `distance` to be a class method and you want to pass in two instances, don't put the function on the prototype, add it as a property of the function itself:

```js
function Shape(x,y){
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
}
// not on the prototype
Shape.distance = function(s1, s2){
    const xDiff = s1.x - s2.x;         
    const yDiff = s1.y - s2.y;
    return Math.sqrt(xDiff*xDiff + yDiff*yDiff);      
}

let sh1 = new Shape(0, 0)
let sh2 = new Shape(3, 4)
console.log(Shape.distance(sh1, sh2))
```